# Ignore returned Fields in Spring Boot Data JPA without using DTOs / with annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jackson

How to ignore the 3 timestamp fields in my `BaseEntity` class used for inheritance from being returned by the controller.

*Not returning them from the DB entirely would also be an option.

```java
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_at", updatable = false)
    private Date createdAt;

    @JsonIgnore
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private Date updatedAt;

    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "deleted_at")
    private Date deletedAt;

}
```

As you see, I tried using:

- `@JsonIgnore` as field annotation (com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore)
- `@JsonIgnoreProperties` as field annotation
- `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"createdAt", "updatedAt", "deletedAt"})` as class annotation
- Disabling `spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS`

`@Transient` seems to be the wrong option for "createdAt" as this needs to be persistet.

***edit***: I'm using Spring 3 (spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.0.5)

Comment: @JsonIgnore is the correct one. I'm using it too. What is wrong with it? The third one should also have the same effect.

Comment: Both do not have any effect. Fields are still present in the response JSON. I'm using Spring 3 but that shouldn't have changed anything?

Comment: Nevermind... I send all request to the DEV server. Oh lord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude the timestamp fields (createdAt, updatedAt, and deletedAt) from being returned, you can use the @JsonIgnoreProperties annotation at the class level.

That should work.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"createdAt", "updatedAt", "deletedAt"})
public abstract class BaseEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private UUID id;

@CreatedDate
@Column(name = "created_at", updatable = false)
private Date createdAt;

@LastModifiedDate
@Column(name = "updated_at")
private Date updatedAt;

@Column(name = "deleted_at")
private Date deletedAt;}
```

Answer (score 1):

@JsonIgnoreProperties should work but you should use this annotation on subclass not base.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"createdAt", "updatedAt", "deletedAt"})
public class SubClass extends BaseEntity
{
 // const, set, get etc.
}
```

Also you can use Mix-ins with object mapper as described here ->
[Inheritance in Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance)